# Mocha says test suceeded but it threw an exception

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I am running some unit tests with mocha. One of my methods called in the unit tests throws an exception. As such, I would like that the test is reported to have failed. However, mocha logs the exception and says the test has succeeded.

```
import * as mocha from 'mocha';

mocha.describe('Tests Disassembler', () => {

it('simple test', () => {
    throw new Error("failed");

});

});
```

Is there any way of telling mocha the test should be reported as failed  if there is an uncaught exception?

Comment: If you run it with mocha, you don't need to import it. and you would only need to use `describe`, not `mocha.describe`. Not sure if that confuses the test runner? Please explain how you are actually executing your tests.

Comment: Look into the done.fail callback for mocha

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the exception was inside a promise.
Solved now.